# Convergent, Bounded, O(1) sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ and these 3 definitions:

> (1) $\{a_n\}$ is bounded: $\exists k>0$ s.t. $-k \leq a_n\leq k$
>    $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> (2) $a_n=O(1)$: $\exists M>0, \bar{n}\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $-M\leq
>  a_n\leq M$ $\forall n \geq \bar{n}$
>
> (3) $\{a_n\}$ is convergent ($\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=b$,
>    $|b|<\infty$):  $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \bar{n}_\epsilon \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $-\epsilon<a_n-b<\epsilon$ $\forall n \geq
> \bar{n}_\epsilon$

I think that

> **(a)** (3) implies (1). In particular, if $\{a_n\}$ is monotone then
>   $k=b$
>
> **(b)** If $\{a_n\}$ is monotone then (1) implies (3)
>
> **(c)** (1) implies (2)
>
> **(d)** (2) does not imply (1)
>
> **(e)** (3) implies (2)
>
> **(f)** (2) does not imply (3)

Are these conclusions correct? Do you see other relations among the three concepts that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** "In particular" is wrong: take $a_{n}=-1+1/n$ then $b=-1$ and (potentially) every $k\ge 1$ works.

**(b)-(c)** Correct.

**(d)** Wrong: (1) and (2) are equivalent.

**(e)-(f)** Correct.

Comment: I have a question regarding (d); (2) seems to say that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded only after a certain $\bar{n}$, while (1) requires boundness $\forall n$. Hence, why you are saying (2)=(1)?

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still obscure. I want to show that (2) implies (1). (2) tells me that after a certain $\bar{n}$ the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded by $M>0$. We don't know what this $M$ is. How can I show that this implies that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded also for $n<\bar{n}$ by $k>0$?

Comment: Because you can choose $k=\max(a_1,\ldots,a_{\overline{n}},M)$: you want to prove that $|a_n| \le k$ for all $n$. If $n\le \overline{n}$ then $a_n \le \max(a_1,\ldots,a_{\overline{n}}) \le k$. If $n>\overline{n}$ then $a_n \le M \le k$.